# Strip empty RTF comments from SQL output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to strip RTF from my comments field in SQL Server. Some of the comments are "empty" as in they only have RTF tags and look like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil MS Sans Serif;}}  {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\lang1033\f0\fs16   \par }
```

I have examined the output in many different ways and everything tells me that those are just space characters in between the curly braces and before the \viewkind4...  However, I cannot replace them. They apparently are some other character?  How can I figure out what those are and remove them?

This does not replace anything:

```
REPLACE(OS.SECCOMMENT, '{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil MS Sans Serif;}}  {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\lang1033\f0\fs16   \par }', '')
```

Comment: What you posted is ascii 32 or a space. My guess is your actual data has some other character. Your replace works perfectly with the data you posted. Try wrapping each character in the ASCII function and see what characters you really have.

Comment: Cast the string to varbinary and look the the values that you think are spaces. And be careful about your assumptions - varchar or nvarchar? But really - this path leads to madness. Using a tool that understands RTF for editing is the preferable approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the character(s) are non-space characters.  I used this to strip out tabs and line feeds and the unwanted "spaces" went away.

```
ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(yourcolumn,char(9),''),char(10),''),char(13),'')))
```